# Proof that all non-trivial zeros of $\zeta (s)$ lie on the strip $0\lt \Re (s)\lt 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

From
$$\zeta (s)=\sum_{n\ge 1}n^{-s}\quad\Re (s)\gt 1$$
we know that
$$\zeta (s)\ne 0\quad\Re (s)\gt 1$$
and from the functional equation for $\zeta (s)$ that
$$\zeta (s)\ne 0,\,\Re (s)\lt 0,\, s\ne -2n,\,n\in\mathbb N.$$
We can also prove
$$\zeta (s)\ne 0\quad\Re (s)=1, \tag*{(*)}$$
possibly using the prime number theorem.

Now, this all proves that if
$$\zeta (s)=0,\,s\ne -2n,\,n\in\mathbb N, \qquad (\dagger )$$
then all the non-trivial zeros lie on the strip $0\lt\Re (s)\lt 1$.
I found numerous proofs of $(*)$, but no proof of $(\dagger)$. The presence of all non-trivial zeros on the critical strip allegedly follows immediately from $(*)$, but I think it does not, since one must rule out the case that $\zeta (s)$ has no zeros except for negative even integers.

Comment: The Euler product on $\Re(s) > 1$, the analytic continuation and the functional equation (together with the non-vanishing of $\Gamma(s)$)  give that there is a pole at $s=1$, trivial zeros at $-2n$ and non-trivial zeros on $\Re(s) \in [0,1]$, together with the non-vanishing on $\Re(s)=1$ it gives that the non-trivial zeros are on $\Re(s) \in (0,1)$. The functional equation gives that $\pi^{-s/2} \Gamma(s/2) \zeta(s)$ is real on $\Re(s)=1/2$ so it has a zero at each change of sign, assuming it has only finitely many gives a contradiction thus there are infinitely many zeros on $\Re(s)=1/2$.

Comment: But how does it give that there are non-trivial zeros on $\Re (s)\in [0,1]$?

Comment: $\pi^{-s/2} \Gamma(s/2) \zeta(s)$ has a sign change at $\approx 1/2+14.13 i$ it is computed to be so, that's one (or two) non-trivial zero

Comment: I should have been more specific — how does it give that *all* non-trivial zeros lie on the strip?

Comment: Because away from $\Re(s) \in [0,1]$ we have an expression in term of the functional equation Gamma terms and the Euler product... The Euler product is non-zero and we know where are the zeros/poles of the Gamma terms. You already asked this in your previous questions, how to multiply two meromorphic functions and find their zeros/poles.

Comment: The location of $\Gamma$'s poles is obvious from $\Gamma(s+1)=s\Gamma(s)$, its non-vanishing is a theorem which follows mainly from that $f(s)=\frac{\pi}{\sin \pi s}-\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)$ is a 2-periodic bounded entire function thus it is constant $=f(i\infty)=0$

Answer (score 1):

Hadamard's theorem implies that the entire function $\xi(s)=(s-1)\pi^{-s/2} \Gamma(s/2) \zeta(s)$ is of exponential order $1$ and maximal type (see the behaviour on the real axis and Stirling formula for maximal type) so it has roughly $R\log R$ roots in a circle of radius $R$ and the sum on the reciprocal absolute value of the roots diverges; since the roots of $\xi$ are the non-trivial roots of $\zeta$ the result (and the correct order of the number of non trivial roots with imaginary part up to $T$ conjectured by Riemann and proved by Von Mangoldt) follow from basic entire function theory

The Euler product of $\zeta$, non-vanishing of $\Gamma= \frac{1}{\Delta}, \Delta$ entire and the functional equation $\xi(s)=\xi(1-s)$ immediately imply that all the zeros must lie in the (closed) critical strip from simple classical complex analysis and the functional equation (however the proof that there are no zeroes on the line $\Re s=1$ is quite hard)